# Word for 'Like a Spiders Web'

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

A nice little oddity which I thought I'd ask about.

I stumbled across the delightful word 'Boustrophedon' in relation to the scanning actions of some printers (inkjet/dot matrix). I believe that this roughly derives from the notion of 'As the ox ploughs the field'.

I mentioned this to a colleague who had a farming background. He stated that in older times, this isn't actually how an ox would have ploughed the field, owing to the direction the plough would have turned the earth.

Apparently, the field would have been ploughed in spiral pattern to ensure that meeting edges of the plough lines would have their earth turned in the same direction, or 'like the spider builds its web'.

Which got me thinking. Is there a colourful noun of some sort that describes this sort of pattern/action?

Comment: Since the word [bostrophedon](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%B2%CE%BF%CF%85%CF%83%CF%84%CF%81%CE%BF%CF%86%CE%B7%CE%B4%CF%8C%CE%BD#Ancient_Greek) meant the same thing in ancient Greek, I would assume that at that time the Greeks, at least, plowed their fields using the back-and-forth pattern.

Comment: Until the addition of coulters and mouldboards, i don't think there was any issue with back-and-forth ploughing as until that time the furrow would be symmetrical.

Comment: My Random House College Dictionary gives the the following as its first definition of gossamer: "A fine filmy cobweb seen on grass or bushes or floating in the air in calm weather, esp. in autumn." The word, cobweb, has negative connotations to both boxers and housewives, but Random House has put a fine spin on it. What's more  I think Random House tacked on "esp. in autumn" to give us some hint as to how the word might could be related to all three of "goose," "summer" and "November." P.S. You are not allowed to use "might could," unless you live in Southwest VA.

Comment: @Airymouse You've lost me, where do geese and summer come into this?

Comment: @PeterShor is correct: [*Iliad* 18.541-49](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0134%3Abook%3D18%3Acard%3D527) indicates that plowing was done back and forth rather than in any spiral.

Comment: @Brian: it's possible that it was done in a spiral in other ancient cultures ... for example, there are so many spiral motifs in ancient Celtic art that I wouldn't be surprised if they plowed in spirals there.

Comment: @Spagirl Remember I said "might could." Etymology ME gos(e)sommer (see GOOSE, SUMMER); possibly first used as a name for late, mild autumn, a time when goose was a favorite dish(cf. G.Gansemonat, November), then transferred to the filmy matter also frequent at that time of year. All this quoted from the same dictionary. Paraphrasing what Hardy said about the mathematics of Ramanujan, it must be true, nobody could be creative enough to make it up.

Comment: @Airymouse my (East) Texan friends might would disagree with you.

Comment: For the pattern in general there is **whorl** or **gyre** or possibly **curlicue**; however, when specifically in a field I would go with ***crop circle***.

Comment: @1006a Fur enough, but you get my drift. I really like the construction, because I think it conveys a hint of skepticism.

Comment: @Airymouse I agree about its utility—I'm from the snowy north, but it's a phrase that I very occasionally find myself using (picked up from my best friend) because nothing else is quite as expressive. I do try to limit it severely, as I'm sure it sounds ridiculous in my very non-southern accent!

Comment: What's wrong with a down to earth phrase like "around and around"?

Comment: Great chat, great comments. Really interesting discussion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you've started with a word of Greek origin, I'd suggest "helicostrophedon" (which sadly does not turn up any hits in the vast knowledge of the internet).

The prefix [helico](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/helico-) means:

> a combining form meaning “spiral”; used with this meaning and as a combining form of helix in the formation of compound words: *helicograph*.

The rest of the word could come from [bostrophedon](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%B2%CE%BF%CF%85%CF%83%CF%84%CF%81%CE%BF%CF%86%CE%B7%CE%B4%CF%8C%CE%BD#Ancient_Greek):

> - στροφή ‎(strophḗ, “turn”) + -δόν ‎(-dón, “in the manner of”).

Or if you really wanted that spider in the picture, try the prefix [arachno](http://wordinfo.info/unit/172/ip:12). But perhaps this would imply a patient predator or quick, patterned movements more than the helical creation of her web.

Comment: Thanks. This is perfect, even if it's never been used before :-)

Answer (score 3):

The word "**arachnean**" is defined by [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/arachnean) as

> having the lightness or fineness of texture of a spider's web

Presumably it's not *too* much of a stretch to use the adjective to refer to the shape of the spider's web as well.